# Connecting files with calendar events

Tags: calendar, files, notes

I'm using Google calendar for all kinds of events. For some events I necessarily create files which can be anything from notes to presentations and so on.

Now the question is whether I can connect these files with their respective events? Usually I have to check my calendar and whatever app I use for notes etc. But sometimes I find it hard to remember if I have already created notes for a particular event because they are not connected.

I assume that Google's calendar app doesn't support my idea but maybe you know a better solution or a different app that will do for me.

Thank you.